# Ajax Call does not Execute in Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use Face API by Microsoft Cognitive Services in my first Cordova Application. I already tried MS Cognitive Services in C# & XAML code, it worked well. I want to use Cognitive Services in JS for my Cordova application
Code:

```
var app = {
initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},
onDeviceReady: function () {
    document.getElementById("take-picture-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
        appState.takingPicture = true;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccessCallback, cameraFailureCallback,
            {
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                targetWidth: 500,
                targetHeight: 500

            }
        );
    });   }   function cameraSuccessCallback(imageUri) {

appState.takingPicture = false;
appState.imageUri = imageUri;
document.getElementById("get-picture-result").src = imageUri;

// Code for Face Detection
var params = {
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "true",
    "returnFaceAttributes": "{string}",
};
var body = { "url" : ""+imageUri };
$.ajax({
    url: "CorrectURL/detect?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "KEY-Value");
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
})
    .done(function (data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    });

// End of Face Detection Code }
```

My Problem is, Ajax call does not get executed. I checked it on Azure Portal I  get 0 number of calls. Can anyone please help me with it?

Thank You

Comment: If you put a console.log before line `appState.takingPicture = false;` does it print? Also, your URL is wrong...

Comment: Whats Wrong in URL?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your program it seems that you want to **send the image file** to back end for processing, but current code is send only the image path that is in **imgUri**.

Below is the working code from my project hope it helps you:-

//Code bit to take photo from camera

```
takePhoto: function () {
                var profile = this;
                var options = {
                    quality: 90,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    correctOrientation: true
                };
                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                    var image = document.getElementById('post-img');
                    image.src = imageData;
                    profile.post.image = imageData;
                }, function (err) {
                    // error
                });
            }
```

//This code bit shows the use of **$cordovaFileTransfer Plugin**

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(config.api_url + "/user/add-post-image", filePath, options).then(function (result) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(result.response);
                    if (response.status === 0) {
                        cb("");
                    } else {
                        cb(response.data.img_path);
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }, function (progress) {
                    console.log(progress);
                });
```

The basic idea is you need to send the file not the file path. So **$cordovaFileTransfer** plugin(http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) can be used to post/put file to server.

*If you still feel any doubt or issue, kindly put your comment I will try updating my answer for your better solution.*

Comment: Why do I need to send only File.? Cognitive Services can accepts file path or File.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL and data fields are incorrect. They should be

```
url: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params)
```

and

```
data: '{"url": ' + '"' + imageUri + '"}'
```

Here is a quickstart that you can take code sample from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/javascript.

Comment: URL and data both are correct, I replaced my URL with "CorrectURL" and about data I tried the way you displayed, and result is No Change.

Comment: url: "CorrectURL/detect?" is not correct. It should read url: CorrectURL + "/detect?". With **"** it becomes a string and hence URL is not correct.

Comment: Man, I used URL same as it is..
url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?"+$.param(params)

Comment: Note also `"returnFaceAttributes": "{string}"` will not work as-is.  `{string}` needs to be a list of attributes.  The possible values are listed [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)